# Rails rake index task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to rake the following index task

```
namespace :search_suggestions do
  desc "Generate search suggestions from items"
  task :index => :environment do
    SearchSuggestion.index_items
  end
end

def self.index_items
  Item.find_each do |item|
    index_term(item.title)
    item.title.split.each { |t| index_term(t) }
  end
end

def self.index_term(term)
  where(term: term.downcase).first_or_initialize.tap do |suggestion|
    suggestion.increment! :popularity
    suggestion.save!
  end
end
```

But when I `rake search_suggestions:index` the columns don't update to the current values Old and deleted data still appears inside the table.

If I do this:

```
def self.index_items
 Search_suggestions.all
  Item.find_each do |item|
    index_term(item.title)
    item.title.split.each { |t| index_term(t) }
  end
end
```

then everything gets updated correctly, but is this the correct approach?

**Update 1**

Flow to delete item

```
 def items_destroy
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
         format.html { redirect_to store_items_index_path(current_store), notice: 'Item was successfully destroyed.' }
         format.json { head :no_content }
    end
 end
```

route.rb

```
match "store/items/destroy"=> "stores#items_destroy", :via => :delete, :as => :store_items_destroy
```

Comment: What is `SearchSuggestion`? Is it a model?

Comment: Yes that is correct... SearchSuggestion is a model and it contains the above actions. Except for the rake task action, that is located `lib/tasks/search_suggestions.rake`

Comment: Why your `SearchSuggestion` model has a method, that do nothing except calling another model `Item`?. Doesn't your `SearchSuggestion` has an association with `Item` model?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AntonTkachov... I'm trying to implement autocomplete from here:http://railscasts.com/episodes/399-autocomplete-search-terms... I don't have any associations inside me search_suggestion model regarding the items model.

Comment: I understand, that Ryan tried to keep it simplier for education purposes, but such code is soooo bad :(. Let me look one more time at your code

Comment: Thanks for the help @AntonTkachov!!! :)

Comment: @AntonTkachov, I was wondering if you found the time to look at my code? I'm kind of stuck with this one here, and I would appreciate your help!

Comment: To be honest I can't get where the issue yet. Can you use some kind of debugger and double check, that where(term: term.downcase).first_or_initialize.tap really returns you a record?

Comment: In general `Search_suggestions.all` string makes no sense at all, so I can't get any idea how it can influence your flow

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, I'll try debugging it later. I was wondering if you could suggest another way to implement this?

Comment: Wrote you better solution implemented with the help of service, but it's different in sense of architecture, not in sense of code itself

Comment: Thanks for the help @ AntonTkachov and upvoted the answer!!! I just made the changes according to the new code you provided. When I add an item and run `rake search_suggestion:index' the item gets added to the `search_suggestion db table` but when I delete it and run the rake command again the item is still there in the `search_suggestion db`

Comment: Can you write an exact flow (how you delete record, etc) as a comment for my answer?

Comment: I just updated the answer with more info.

Comment: Any ideas @AntonTkachov!!!

Comment: You just destroy an item, but `SearchSuggestion` has no idea at all, that item was removed/etc... `SearchSuggestion` doesn't depend on `Item`. I've updated my answer and wrote my concern there

Comment: Does my answer helped you?

Answer (score 1):

`lib/tasks/search_suggestions.rake`:

```
namespace :search_suggestions do
  desc "Generate search suggestions from items"
  task :index => :environment do
    IndexItemsService.new.call
  end
end
```

`app/services/index_items_service.rb`:

```
class IndexItemsService
  def call
    Item.find_each do |item|
      SearchSuggestion.index_terms([item.title].concat(item.title.split))
    end
    return true
  end
end
```

`app/models/search_suggestion.rb`:

```
class SearchSuggestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  // other code
  def self.index_terms(terms)
    terms.each do |term|
      where(term: term.downcase).first_or_initialize.tap do |suggestion|
        suggestion.increment! :popularity
        suggestion.save!
      end
    end
  end
  // other code
end
```

`app/controllers/items_controller.rb`:

```
def destroy
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  SearchSuggestion.where(term: [item.title].concat(item.title.split)).destroy_all
  @item.destroy
end
```

DANGER! This mostly will work, but it has obvious bug. Let's imagine we have 2 items with titles: 'Hello Anton' and 'Hello Theopap'. Both of them were indexed. If we delete 'Hello Anton' it will destroy suggestions for 'Hello Anton' which is ok, 'Anton' which is ok, but it will also destroy suggestions for 'Hello', that are intersect between our 2 items. So suggestions for second item's 'Hello' will be also removed. I don't see any real workaround to fix this, without changing architecture, etc